# C# Duplicate Data Problem

Tags: c#, ienumerable, duplicate-data

I am having problems with duplicate data being inserted in to the database, am I passing a wrong parameter in the `IEnumerable<Location>`?

It doesn't bring up any errors when I debug the app.

```
IEnumerable<Location> locations = context.Locations.Where(l => l.FacebookID == facebookID);

if (locations.Count() == 0)
{
    Location newLocation = new Location();

    newLocation.FacebookID = locationID;

    newLocation.Description = locationValue;

    IGeoCoder geoCoder = new GoogleGeoCoder(GoogleAPIKey);
    Address[] addresses = geoCoder.GeoCode(locationValue);

    if (addresses.Length > 0)
    {
        // Let's assume the first one is good enough
        Address address = addresses[0];

         newLocation.Latitude= address.Coordinates.Latitude.ToString();
         newLocation.Longitude = address.Coordinates.Longitude.ToString();
        // Use location.Latitude and location.Longitude

    }

    context.Locations.AddObject(newLocation);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing you did not mean to do this:

```
newLocation.FacebookID = locationID;
```

But rather this:

```
newLocation.FacebookID = facebookID;
```

Basically you are creating multiple records, with the same facebookId, as you actually used the locationID instead.

Comment: IEnumerable<Location> locations = context.Locations.Where(l => l.FacebookID == locationID); seemed to do the trick for me, changing it from facebook = facebookid to locationID did the trick :)